# I am very interested in using this site, but even after reading the response to how points can be earned,

Tags: discussion

I am unable to ask or answer a question because I am missing some key information or because I am misunderstanding the information presented. So how does one increase one's reputation points, please?

Comment: This question is [answered on the main Meta.Stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges) site.

Comment: [Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) has a lot of information you might want to read including [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: You don't need reputation to ask or answer questions. You can do that even at 1 rep. If you ask good questions or provide helpful answers, you will earn more rep, and progressively more abilities, like voting on posts, commenting, and eventually administrative tools like putting questions in hold which need repair, or deleting inappropriate content. But you don't need any of that to get started (and in fact you are never required to do any of that additional stuff): you can ask and answer today. Welcome.

Comment: Your question title is not a duplicate , but the answers respond perfectly to your request. Welcome and have fun!

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: was that really necessary?

Comment: @DanBron Pamela is a drive-by visitor, I doubt if the downvotes swayed her decision to remain and contribute, or become a lurker. If indeed that.